# How to get LISS IV Imagery data?

Tags: data, imagery

I'm looking for LISS-IV Imagery data for the capstone project. I have LISS-III data but that has some water marks like clouds and their shadows in the background.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if LISS IV is the camera used on the Resourcesat-2 satellite.  I managed to find [**this page**](http://geoawesomeness.com/free-satellite-data-from-indian-resourcesat-2-via-inpe/) which states you can freely download imagery from this [**site**](http://www.dgi.inpe.br/CDSR/).  All you need to do is register.

You can specify cloud cover percentages in your search.  In fact, it's done by quarters of the image like this:

```
Q1|Q2
-----
Q3|Q4
```